# turn on/off hardware key backlight

Tags: android, led, backlight

Before i ask this question, i've realized it, but it is based on some conditions.

Try1: Change the chmod of file '/sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness' to 777, the original file is readable but not writeable, then write '1' to this file to turn on led backlight, '0' to turn off. However, i don't want to change the property of this file.

Try2: something like 'Try 1', that is: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness");` to turn off, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness");` to turn on, but this requires your phone has been rooted or you're a super user when execute the code. So, it isn't the solution that i want.

My thought: i can follow the way that Android System itself turn on/off the led backlight when we touch key like 'Menu', 'Home', 'Back'. But, i don't know how to track or find the ralated code in Android Open Source Code.

I do really appreciate any tip, any thought or any possible way that you provide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152053/android-turn-off-hardware-key-lights

Comment: @RobinHood  i've read that post before, and it has little help to me, Thanks any way :)

Comment: I'm also deadly looking forward to a solution. layoutParams.buttonBrightness = 0.0f; only works when an app starts.