# turn on /off hardware key light (Home, Menu, Back)

Tags: android, android-hardware

In my application i want to turn on /off the hardware key back light(Home, Menu, Back) programatically.I searched many more but they will work on rooted device but i want for all whether its rooted or not.Can any one tell me that how can i do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - turn off hardware key lights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152053/android-turn-off-hardware-key-lights)

Comment: Yes, that will work on rooted devices but i want for all Whether it is rooted or not

Answer (score -1):

I got the below answer that is working perfactly

```
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
      wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK  ,
        "My wakelook");
      wakeLock.acquire();
```

to release wakelock used below code

```
 wakeLock.release();
```